# print/print dialog validation by selenium Automation

Tags: selenium-webdriver, autoit

Has anyone automated validating print/print dialog functionality output anytime?? or if any idea on the same please let me know here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems similar to the "File Open Dialog" problem.
My general remark in this case is as follows, when an external dialog (not inside HTML) called by the browser opens, the browser suspends communication with external scripts, including Selenium, until the operation that was called is performed.
In other words, run the AutoIt script first and then call the print dialog, never the other way around.